# Clear Firemonkey TListView search text

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

```
ListView1.items.filter := nil;
```

I understand that the above will clear the filter of a listview however if the **Search** is visible for the listview and something is typed into it, is there anyway of clearing the text from it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for I := 0 to ListView1.Controls.Count-1 do
  if ListView1.Controls[I] is TSearchBox then
  begin
    TSearchBox(ListView1.Controls[I]).Text := '';
  end;
```

(based on DocWiki!)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Dsm, by answer. I will just suggest a trick to get `TSearchBox` just one time and store in a variable. Now it is not necessary to loop through the `TListView.Controls` every time. For example:

```
uses
 ..., FMX.SearchBox;

var
  SearchBox_ListView1: TSearchBox = nil;

...

if not Assigned(searchBox_listview1) then 
  for I := 0 to ListView1.Controls.Count-1 do
    if ListView1.Controls[I] is TSearchBox then
    begin
      SearchBox_listview1 := TSearchBox(ListView1.Controls[I]);
      Break;
    End;

... 

if Assigned(SearchBox_listview1) then
  SearchBox_listview1.Text := '';
```