# Clear Firemonkey TListView search text (C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I want to clear the ListView's search box text in C++.  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266827/clear-firemonkey-tlistview-search-text) to doing this in pascal but I've been unable to convert this to C++ (due to my ignorance).

Seems like it should be something simple like:

```
ListView1->SearchBox->Clear();
```

thanks, russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <FMX.SearchBox.hpp>

TSearchBox *SearchBox_ListView1 = nullptr;

...

for(int i = 0; i < ListView1->Controls->Count; ++i)
{
    SearchBox_ListView1 = dynamic_cast<TSearchBox*>(ListView1->Controls[i]);
    if (SearchBox_ListView1)
        break;
}

... 

if (SearchBox_ListView1)
    SearchBox_ListView1->Text = L"";
```